# Return docker to a previous state

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file to run postgres db like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.2
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Then I can start it with this command:

```
docker-compose up postgres
```

Then I run some scripts to create a new schema, then create tables and populate them with some data.

At this point the db is ready to be used by an application, make some tests, insert/update/delete data in tables, etc.

After running these tests is there any way to go back or restore the db to the status it was before running the tests?

Maybe there's some command in docker to take a snapshot.

Is that possible?

Comment: you could destroy and spin up the same container when you wanna reset.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a Dockerfile, include your scripts in it and build an image that contains your modified database. Once you have that, just use this same image in your docker-compose file. You can then just use `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` and you'll have the container in it's previous state.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thank you for your comment, I did some research based on your answer and it really help me. Thank you